# Where to place a debug log files for my daemon app?

Tags: c, linux

I am using C language and Linux as my programming platform.

I am learning how to create a daemon, and I want to create a log file so that I write a debug message in my daemon. My question is where should I put the log file in my system. Should I put it in the var folder?

Please advice.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `syslog` and let the administrator decided where the log is written.

Answer (score 3):

`/var/log/{app name}` I believe is the standard location.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a matter of taste, but `/var/log/` or `/etc/log/` sounds reasonable to me. You should also consider using `syslog` (see http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog).

Comment: The problem with trying to write explicitly to /var/log (or /etc/log, probably) is that only root has write permission there. Using syslog gets around that issue.